# Using AS3(actionscript3)regular expression i need to retrieve data between double quotes

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I am having raw data like this --> function geoip_country_code(){return"IN"}function geoip_country_name(){return"India"}function geoip_city(){return"Chennai"}function geoip_region(){return"TN"}function geoip_region_name(){return"Tamil Nadu"}function geoip_latitude(){return"13.052414"}function geoip_longitude(){return"80.250825"}function geoip_postal_code(){return""}function geoip_area_code(){return"0"}function geoip_metro_code(){return"0"}

I need to retrieve the data between double quotes. That's i need IN,India,Chennai likewise.

I don't know RegExp. so anyone kindly give solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: formatting should be done

Comment: Check out RegExr by Grant Skinner (http://www.regexr.com), that is IMHO the perfect tool to learn & build regular expressions for AS projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regular Expression you're looking for is

```
/"([^"]*)"/
```

Explanation: match two quotes and any number (`*`) of characters in between that are not a quote (`^"`). The capture group `(…)` will return you the desired characters.

I don't know ActionScript too well, but [String.match](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match()) should be the right choice.

Comment: Thanks... That solved my major problem.. i can start work on that project.But it shows IN only(debug like this "IN",IN). if the RegExp brings all the data inside the double qoute than that would be more useful. And Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Add a global flag like this: `/"([^"]*)"/g`